# How can I hardcode input with the "select" system call in C?

Tags: c, unix, hardcode

If I understand this system call "select" correctly,

Answer (score 1):

?????

If you don't want user input ... then just don't ask for user input!

If you want to "automate" user input, why not run your program with "myprog < myinput.txt"?

Am I missing something???

Comment: I do want user input, I just don't want to have to type in the same thing everytime. Also for my situation I can't control how the program is setup (I can't specify arguments); all I can do is edit the code.